# How to convert the MultipartFile into byte array in spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, request

I'm working on a spring boot project where I use postgresql as my database. In my project I need to create an event and save the details of the event along with the event flyer. I'm passing the event flyer to the eventController as a multipartFile and in the Service class I will convert it to a byte array using method `getBytes()` . I implemented the code as follows and tried to send a request using postman.

This is my Event Entity :

```
`package com.example.attendingsystembackend.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Lob;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid",strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Event name cannot be blank")
    private String eventName;

    private String eventType;

    @NotBlank(message = "Event location cannot be blank")
    private String location;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime startTime;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime endTime;

    @Lob
    private byte[] eventFlyer;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public String getEventType() {
        return eventType;
    }

    public void setEventType(String eventType) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(LocalDateTime startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(LocalDateTime endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public byte[] getEventFlyer() {
        return eventFlyer;
    }

    public void setEventFlyer(byte[] eventFlyer) {
        this.eventFlyer = eventFlyer;
    }
}`
```

And this is my event service class:

```
package com.example.attendingsystembackend.service;

import com.example.attendingsystembackend.model.Event;
import com.example.attendingsystembackend.repository.EventRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;

@Service
public class EventService {

    private final EventRepository eventRepository;

    @Autowired
    public EventService(EventRepository eventRepository) {
        this.eventRepository = eventRepository;
    }

    public void saveEvent(MultipartFile file, Event event) throws IOException {

        Event newEvent=new Event();

        newEvent.setEventName(event.getEventName());
        newEvent.setEventType(event.getEventType());
        newEvent.setLocation(event.getLocation());
        newEvent.setStartTime(event.getStartTime());
        newEvent.setEndTime(event.getEndTime());

        if(file!=null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            byte[] fileBytes = file.getBytes();
            newEvent.setEventFlyer(fileBytes);
        }else{
            newEvent.setEventFlyer(null);
        }

        eventRepository.save(newEvent);
    }

    }
```

And here is my event controller class:

```
package com.example.attendingsystembackend.controller;

import com.example.attendingsystembackend.model.Event;
import com.example.attendingsystembackend.service.EventService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/event")
public class EventController {

    private final EventService eventService;

    @Autowired
    public EventController(EventService eventService) {
        this.eventService = eventService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value="saveEvent")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveEvent(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file, Event event) {
        try {
            eventService.saveEvent(file,event);

            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                    .body(String.format("Event saved succesfully with file: %s", file.getOriginalFilename()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .body(String.format("Could not save the event: %s!", e));
        }
    }
}
```

And tried to send request using postman as follows:

[image]

But Unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
Validation failed for argument [1] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.example.attendingsystembackend.controller.EventController.saveEvent(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,com.example.attendingsystembackend.model.Event): [Field error in object 'event' on field 'eventFlyer': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@42f6b750]; codes [typeMismatch.event.eventFlyer,typeMismatch.eventFlyer,typeMismatch.[B,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [event.eventFlyer,eventFlyer]; arguments []; default message [eventFlyer]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'byte[]' for property 'eventFlyer'; Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'byte' for property 'eventFlyer[0]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile']] ]
```

As I feel the error occured when converting `MultiPartFile` to `byte[]`  Can someone help me with this issue? What is the mistake I have done here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed two things here,

1). In your post method you have sending a multipart file and event class. but you sending them as @Request param.. instead do this

```
@PostMapping(value="saveEvent")
public ResponseEntity<String> saveEvent(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("body") Event event) // you can also pass json as string value and then map into objects
```

2). your request from the postman should be like this.(sample)

[image]

Comment: Yeah it worked! Thank you so much for your prompt and helpful response! Your answer solved my issue perfectly and saved me.